# draw SVG image into CanvasRenderingContext2D

Tags: javascript, image, svg

Is it possible to do something like this

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'img.svg';
context.drawImage(image, x, y); // context is an instance of CanvasRenderingContext2D
```

with a SVG image? Actually this code works, but I think the image is converted to .jpg or similar, because if I try to zoom the browser page the image becomes coarse.

**Clarification** : The image should be re-drawn many times in the canvas context (i.e. for movements), so suggestions like "*use this library*" should consider this fact.

**EDIT**

From previous discussions, the issue seems to be due to canvas properties (canvas is not browser-zoomable) and not due to incorrect loading. Can I get and modify (eventually) this property of canvas to realize my purpose? I have to draw necessarily on canvas, no other options unfortunately.

Comment: Canvas is a pixel based renderer and will not re-render or resize when zoomed in contrary to a regular vectoral image. You should manually scale and re-render the svg IMO.

Comment: @AliNaciErdem how is possible? And what is svg IMO?

Comment: IMO = In My Opinion.

Comment: Do you want the canvas to be browser-zoomable or a zoom feature in your application?

Comment: @AliNaciErdem I simply want to have a SVG image rather than JPEG or PNG, thus my image should be scalable if I zoom my browser page. To answer your question, yes, I want the canvas to be browser-zoomable.

Comment: Then, it is not possible with a canvas. The only option is trying to get browser-zoom values and manage your canvas size/scaling accordingly. Re-ask your question keeping this in mind.

Comment: @AliNaciErdem then you're saying that the issue of scaling is not due to incorrect loading of image but is due to canvas properties?

Comment: @FabrizioMorello Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Translate rendered svg according to the wanted zoom level.

[How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

explains browser-zoom level detection. And you can use fabricjs for canvas manipulation (http://fabricjs.com/).